# Can be switch var webdrriverio from require('webdriverio ') to require('webdriverjs-angular') in the same script

Tags: webdriver-io

We have the application where the login page is Non Angular and the other pages uses angular. If we start the var webdriverio = require('webdriverio'), we are able to script but we wanted to use mocha and chai for our scripting, so the best way is to use require('webdriverjs-angular') for Angular pages. I tried using require('webdriverjs-angular') for login page and gets timeout as excepted. I tried protractor where I was able to switch and we had other issue in locating element inside iframe so we switched to webdriverio. Please can you help us and let us know can we switch the require from webdriverio to webdriverjs-angular in the same code. If yes, please provide the sample code

Comment: it maybe help you to solve your issues
https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverjs-angular its may be help you

Comment: The solution is not getting executed. Im not the core developer basically, I there any way to export or inherite webdriverjs-angular to webdriverio so that I can use waitforAngular and use one require to navigate angular and non angular page

Comment: The code that is provided is that, The html is using Angular and they have showed tat we can use webdriverIO to script - Regular-client.js however angular-client.js is using Angularjs. That is fine. As told above, we are able to use WebdriverIO for scripting our Angular and non angular pages using Wait or pause, that is not the correct for if we are having Angular pages. So we want to have some thing that Angular js can be used for Non angular page, if we can inherit the webdriver IO. The Application that is given GIt is Angular.

Comment: I took this solution, this is where the application is angular and they have used webdriverIO to automate angular and Webdriverjs-angular to automate angular as expected. The issue I have is...Login is Non angular means I should take webdriverjs-angular and inherit the webdriverIO so ensure that the tool/flow work for both pages. Please any suggestion is appreciated.